# Sealed or non-sealed immersion cold-brew

Tags: cold-brew

What's the difference (pros/cons) on brewing full-immersion cold-brew (resting at the refrigerator by night) hermetically sealed (closed mason jar) vs non-sealed (opened mason jar, Toddy, french-press, etc) ?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess, but I suppose using a non-sealed container would speed up oxidation and deterioration of the coffee due to continuous exposure to atmospheric oxygen, just as storing the dry beans in an open container would.

However, from my own experience, 12 to 24 hours of such exposure would not yield a perceptibly different taste. What's more important is that you store the finished product in a sealed container, preferably with as little air as possible (I use a water bottle).

On the other hand, also in my experience, cold-brewing with a french press is more convenient, since one can simply push down the plunger and pour the finished product as opposed to lengthy fumbling with filters.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but I have a 2 cup french press, so I prefer to my chemex do the filtering process jajaj My intuition told me that sealed would reduce the oxidising process, but I don't know which would be better, just air (non-sealed) or full of CO2 (sealed)

Comment: @OmarMiranda I also have a small french press (0.3l), but I find that making my cold-brew in smaller batches isn't worse than larger batches. It's arguably better in terms of both taste (less storage time) and convenience (having 2-3 days worth of coffee in a teeny tiny bottle), and it also turns the preparation into something of a ritual.
In any case, since the difference in taste seems to be minuscule (at least to me), use whatever's more convenient

Comment: Thanks @FlashCactus. Due to the size of my mason jar, I tend to filled it up (to avoid the presence of Oxygen) and that's why I asked this on the first place. I'm gonna try making a small batch sealed :)